# Bootstrap multi-select is not adding "open" class to div , hence no drop down is displayed

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, listbox, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using bootstrap multiselect listbox but bootstrap is not adding "open" class to the div hence drop down is not displayed.

HTML

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">

<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link href="../Styles/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../Styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
    $(function ()
    {
        $('[id*=Listbox1]').multiselect({
            maxHeight: 200,
            enableFiltering: true,
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<asp:ListBox ID="Listbox1" ClientIDMode="Static" SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="70px" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="li1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Are scripts being rendered anywhere else?